# PowerBI On Premise - Report not refreshing using Direct Query and Auto Page Refresh / Change Detection

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

As the title states, I'm having some issues with the most current version (Sept 2021) of PowerBI Reporting Services on premise.

The report will automatically refresh in PowerBI Desktop, but when deployed to the PowerBI Reporting Server it will not.

The data source is a live SQL Server (Direct Query) and the data is not imported.

I'm using Chrome and have disabled any ad blocking extensions that might cause issues, but the report won't refresh at the interval I have set.

This is for a kiosk, so I was hoping these solutions worked. It appears that PowerBI Reporting Services doesn't support it.

Any suggestions? I'd like this to be as hands off as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the September 2021 release of PowerBI Reporting Services, it appears this isn't an option. It works for PowerBI Desktop and Web, but not on premise PowerBI.

See this thread for more info: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Automatic-Page-Refresh-not-working-as-expected/td-p/2130612